# List-unsubscribe mail headers phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm attempting to have an Unsubscribe link in the email header using phpmailer.  So far only the email is shown not the unsubscribe link.

```
$mail->From= 'test@test.com';
            $mail->FromName  =  'Test';


            $i = 0;
            foreach($emails as $email) {

                if (strpos($email, '@') !== false) {    
                    $mail->AddBCC($email);
                }

                $i++;
            }
        $mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe:  <no-reply@test.com>,<".base_url()."unsubscribe/".$unique_unsub.">");


        $subject = "test";

        $message = "testing";
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;

        $mail->Send();
```

How do i solve?

Comment: You've got `SMTPDebug = 1` set so you should be able to see the actual header sent in your message during the DATA command in the SMTP session. You're setting the header in the correct way, but the value you're setting it to is invalid, so it's in the message, but it's being ignored by your client because the format is wrong - as tadman's answer suggests. Also it looks like you're using an old version of PHPMailer - [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 4):

That's the wrong format. What you want is:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe:  <mailto:no-reply@test.com>,<".base_url()."unsubscribe/".$unique_unsub.">");
```

Where these components must be prefixed with `mailto:` or `http:`, you can't just have a bare address.

More information on this header is available at the [List Unsubscribe site](http://www.list-unsubscribe.com).